# Building app for native use (ios and android) - store large audio files locally for offline use

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, local-storage

I'm currently planning on building an application using the ionic framework wrapping angularJS and cordova.

The app, once downloaded must be able to play its own audio files that were bundled with the application without streaming them from the internet.

Can anyone give guidance as to whether the phones 'hard drive' can be accessed to store audio files on? Or, if not whether the $localstorage facility would be suitable for storing audio files up to perhaps 50Mb?

Answer (score 0):

In the [api docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html) you can find the info for it.

I haven't used cordova yet but that should work.

Localstorage in browser is limited to 2.5MB, 5MB, 10 MB or unlimited depending on used browser. Not sure how it is handled in a native webview but probably similar to these limits.

In this [blog post](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/07/15/Cordova-Sample-Reading-a-text-file) is a text read demo that could also help.